# C# to loop through folder until it finds the correct files

Tags: c#, .net

I’m running a batch to do an update to my sql table. I’m using windows scheduler to run the batch file. Each day files come in at different time. Sometime they come in after my scheduled time therefore the batch file doesn’t run when there’s no file before the scheduled task in the folder. I want to create a c# program where it will loop through the folder until it finds the files and then move to the next step in the batch file. Basically my goal is to create a program that will look for those particular files and once they finds the correct files then it will start the update. I’m new to programming and need some direction. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Directory.GetFiles would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 5):

Read about `FileSystemWatcher` Class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Looping will consume 100% of CPU

Comment: Looping can work if you add sleeps, but still an event based solution is much better.

Comment: @MrFox active wait is a last century solution for me ;)

Comment: Just saying it don't have to take 100% of CPU. Loops are still useful in games, the main game loop :)

Comment: I got to the point where it will look for the files. I would like to know how I can move to the next step(batch file statement) once it has all the files. Thnaks.