# C# polling to monitor folder

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# to loop through folder until it finds the correct files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918550/c-sharp-to-loop-through-folder-until-it-finds-the-correct-files)

Is it possible to use c# polling to monitor a folder for "required" files? I am running a batch file which requires certain files to be in the folder. If the files are not there and batch job cancels automatically. I am just wondering if I can use ploling to monitor the folder and once they are available I would like the batch file to continue. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could poll a folder (via [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) and similar methods) to look for the existence of files.

However, you might want to consider using [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).  It allows you to directly receive events as files are added or removed from a folder.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes

Answer (score 0):

you can use a backgroundworker and check for files existence using:

```
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists("FullAddressFileName"))
                {
                    //stop batch 

                }
```